# Hough circle transform in opencv not detecting any circles

Tags: java, opencv

I'm writing a program to detect a circle of a particular color in an image, using the Houghcircles() method.

```
Imgproc.HoughCircles(thresholdedImg,circles,Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1d,100,200,100,1,100);
```

Printing the circles Mat after this statement gives me this, even when I run the program for an image of a perfect circle:

```
Mat [ 0*0*CV_8UC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x894140, dataAddr=0x0 ]
```

The method clearly didn't the circle as the number of rows and columns is zero.

Here's the entire code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    Mat srcImg = imread("img.png");

    Mat thresholdedImg = new Mat(srcImg.rows(),srcImg.cols(),CvType.CV_8UC1);

    byte black[] = {0,0,0};
    byte w = getUnsignedByte(255);
    byte white[] = {w,w,w};

    double requiredBlue[] = {225.0,105.0,65.0}; // BGR values of shade to be detected


    for(int i=0;i<srcImg.rows();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<srcImg.cols();j++) {
            double currentPixel[] = srcImg.get(i,j);    
            if(currentPixel[0]==requiredBlue[0] && currentPixel[1]==requiredBlue[1] && currentPixel[2]==requiredBlue[2])
                thresholdedImg.put(i, j, black);
            else
                thresholdedImg.put(i, j, white);
        }
    }

    Mat circles = new Mat(srcImg.rows(),srcImg.cols(),CvType.CV_8UC1);

    Imgproc.HoughCircles(thresholdedImg,circles,Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1d,100,200,100,1,100);

    displayImage(Mat2BufferedImage(circles));
}
```

Mat2BufferedImage() in the last line throws an exception due to the empty Mat, as expected:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be > 0

I tested Mat2BufferedImage() with non-empty Mats and it works. Let me know if I should post it too.

I looked for solutions before posting and all the posts I came across had to do with improper detection; none of them had Houghcircles() generate an empty Mat.

[Here is the image I get after thresholding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHecc.png)

Comment: Did you check thresholdedImg ? Is it really contains circle ? Can you post thresholdedImg here? This article may help: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/

Comment: That is actually one of the articles I referred for the program. It doesn't help with my current problem.
I edited my post to include thresholdedImg.

Comment: Circle seems too small, did you try with larger images ? Or you need to reduce threshold for hough transform circle detector. I mean "param_2 = 100*: Threshold for center detection."

Comment: Reducing the threshold worked. Thanks!

Comment: podt sample images